# AngularJS - Karma testing with providers and injections

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-providers

I am having a lot of trouble to write the unit test case for a provider that contains some injections.

The particular provider is:

```
(function () {
angular
    .module('core.router', [])
    .provider('routerHelper', routerHelperProvider);

routerHelperProvider.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

/**
 * This method Initializes the Router Helper provider to be used by all modules
 *
 * @param $stateProvider
 * @param $urlRouterProvider
 */
function routerHelperProvider($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    this.$get = routerHelperService;

    routerHelperService.$inject = ['$state'];

    /**
     * This method sets the methods to be used by the helper
     *
     * @param $state
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    function routerHelperService($state) {
        var hasOtherwise = false;

        return {
            configureStates: configureStates,
            getStates: getStates
        };

        /**
         * This method configures all the states to be used by the application
         *
         * @param {!String[]} states
         * @param {!String} otherwisePath
         */
        function configureStates(states, otherwisePath) {
            states.forEach(function (state) {
                //console.log("adding state", state.state, "with config", state.config);
                $stateProvider.state(state.state, state.config);
            });
            if (otherwisePath && !hasOtherwise) {
                hasOtherwise = true;
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(otherwisePath);
            }
        }

        /**
         * This method returns the states to be used by the application
         *
         * @return {Object}
         */
        function getStates() {
            return $state.get();
        }
    }
}  })();
```

The basic unit test is:

```
'use strict';

describe('core.router test', function () {

    // All Service injections
    var $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider;

    // Mocks
    var m_url = function () {
    };
    var m_state = function () {
    };

    // Others
    var routerHelper, urlRouter, state, base;

    // Before statements
    beforeEach(module('core.router', function ($provide, _routerHelperProvider_) {
        $provide.value('$urlRouterProvider', m_url);
        $provide.value('$stateProvider', m_state);
        base = _routerHelperProvider_;
    }));

    // Starting the Factory
    beforeEach(inject(function (_routerHelper_, _$urlRouter_, _$state_) {
        routerHelper = _routerHelper_;
        urlRouter = _$urlRouter_;
        state = _$state_;
    }));

    describe('when testing it', function () {
        it('should return true', function () {

            //var abc = routerHelper.getStates();

            expect(1).toEqual(1);
        });
    });
});
```

I keep getting errors like:

> - Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown Provider: $stateProvider
> - Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown Provider: $urlRouterProvider
> - Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown Provider: routerHelperProvider

I tried several different module instantiations and several different injections, but I can't seem to make it work. When I take out the injections (`$stateProvider`, `$urlRouterProvider` and `$state`), the unit test is straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this would be the solution, bringing some complexity because the provider is using both the $state and $stateProvider:

```
'use strict';

describe('core.router test', function () {

    // All Provider injections
    var $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider;

    // Mocks
    var m_urlProvider = mockDataCore.urlRouterProvider();
    var m_stateProvider = mockDataCore.stateProvider();
    var m_state = mockDataCore.state();

    // Others
    var routerHelper, base;

    // Define the mock providers
    beforeEach(function(){
        module(function($provide){
            $provide.provider('$urlRouter', m_urlProvider);
            $provide.provider('$state', m_stateProvider);
        });
    });

    // Start the module with the internal mock
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('core.router', function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('$state', m_state);
        });
    });

    // Load the provider with module to be able to call its configuration methods
    beforeEach(function () {
        module(['routerHelperProvider', function (_$urlRouterProvider_, _$stateProvider_, _routerHelperProvider_) {
            $urlRouterProvider = _$urlRouterProvider_;
            $stateProvider = _$stateProvider_;
            base = _routerHelperProvider_;
        }]);
    });

    // Inject and start the provider
    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(['routerHelper', function (_routerHelper_, $state) {
            routerHelper = _routerHelper_;
        }]);
    });

    // test cases
    describe('when adding one state and no "otherwise"', function () {
        it('otherwise should not be called and state should be saved to state list', function () {

            spyOn(m_urlProvider, "otherwise");
            spyOn(m_stateProvider, "state");

            var simpleState = [{
                state : "home",
                config : {
                    url: "/home"
                }}];

            routerHelper.configureStates(simpleState);

            expect(m_urlProvider.otherwise).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(m_stateProvider.state).toHaveBeenCalledWith("home", {url: "/home"});
        });
    });

    describe('when getting the states', function () {
        it('should return the states', function () {

            spyOn(m_state, "get");

            var states = routerHelper.getStates();

            expect(m_state.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

The mock methods are:

```
var mockDataCore = (function () {
return {
    urlRouterProvider: urlRouterProvider,
    stateProvider: stateProvider,
    state: state
};

function urlRouterProvider() {
    return {
        otherwise: function () { /* void  */
        },
        $get: function () {  /* void  */
        }
    };
}

function stateProvider() {
    return {
        state: function () { /* void  */
        },
        $get: function () {  /* void  */
        }
    };
}

function state() {
    return {
        get: function () {
            return {};
        },
        go: function () {  /* void  */
        }
    };
}})();
```

Of course it doesn't cover all the tests for this provider, but the rest of them are pretty straight forward..